# Theme arguments in flair URL unusable in some forums

Tags: feature-request, support, flair

As explained on [the flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair):

> to change the theme, add `?theme=clean` or `?theme=dark` or `?theme=hotdog` to the end of the image URL

The majority of the time, this works fine.  However, I wanted to add my flair to my signature on a PHPBB2 forum.  I can't find the documentation on it at the moment, but I could have sworn that I read that BBCode image tags are only converted to HTML image tags when the image URL "appears to be an image URL."  Meaning, a flair URL of `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/HASH.png` is valid, but `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/HASH.png?theme=clean` is *not* valid because their parser no longer considers it to be an image URL.

I also tried `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/HASH.png?theme=clean&x=.png` but I guess it was smart enough to detect that arguments were being used, still.

Granted it's not a huge deal that I'm stuck on the default theme, but the best fix for my situation would probably be to set up the URL handling such that I can do `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/themes/clean/HASH.png` to keep a "true" image URL.

Failing that, does anyone know of a workaround for this issue on PHPBB forums?

---

Also, as a *minor* rider/request to this question, offering pre-made BBCode for the flair on the flair page would have saved me a minute.

Comment: It isn't official, but you can take a look at http://stackflair.com which puts the format options in the middle of the url so as to preserve the file extension.

Comment: @Rebecca: If nothing "official" happens, that indeed seems to be a very good workaround.  Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

You can generally cheat this by doing things like arbitrarily adding a fake param on the end that ends with `.png` or `.jpg`

`http://example.com/image.png?theme=clean&x=file.png`

But if you already tried that, I guess not.

Comment: At [this forum](http://www.pgdp.net/phpBB2/index.php), `
[img]http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2bbf9fe446fe4a8c8f1d832554b19079.png?theme=clean&x=x.png[/img]` does not get rendered as an image, but `[img]http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/2bbf9fe446fe4a8c8f1d832554b19079.png[/img]` does.